What does "zigs when others zag" mean?
From Merriam-Webster's entry for zig

zigs when others zag.

From Senate rankings: 5 seats most likely to flip:

“It’s going to be tough,” one Democratic operative conceded. “But Montana has that ability to zag when people zig.”

Zig and zag are synonymous, and both means to make a sharp turn, correct? What does the example mean?
When the order between zig and zag is exchanged, does it still mean the same, as "zag when others zig" in the second example?

To zig and to zag both mean to make a sharp turn, but when used together they usually mean turning in different directions, such that when alternating, the turns create a zig-zag:

Metaphorically, zigging when others zag means doing something else or going in a different direction than others. A more common idiom with a similar explanation is to zig when one should zag:

To move in a particular direction when one should move in a different direction in order to avoid some obstacle or impediment. A reference to moving from side to side in a zigzag pattern.

In the sentence in question, the Democratic operative claims that Montana can sometimes not follow what the people (presumably in other states) are doing - in an election context, this means that it's possible that the results of Montana elections will not follow nationwide trends.

Yes, but this does not explain the Montana reference at all.

@Lambie It seems to, to me. I take it to mean "Montana ['s voting trends] can sometimes run counter to larger trends among similar demographics."

@Lambie I'm not sure what your issue is. Metaphorically, zigging when others zag means doing something else or going in a different direction than others. - is this not enough of an answer to the question in the title? I trust that the OP can apply this general definition to the specific example - I don't agree with you that the full quote is needed, the meaning is "Montana can sometimes act in a way that's contrary to other states" and the rest is interpretation in context.

I am not talking about zigzagging. I'm talking about the rest of the use in that sentence. You can't actually tell what it means exactly without the previous sentence. You don't even mention Montana in your explanation. That's my issue.

@Lambie the question was about the meaning of the idiom. The idiom has an exact meaning - "to do something differently than most". You don't need the context to get that meaning, and applying that meaning to the context goes outside of linguistic knowledge and into interpretation. And I think a general definition is going to be more useful - if the OP encounters this or a similar phrase again in a different context, they can use the same definition, or use the provided etymology to deduce the exact meaning. Telling them "it means Montana will vote Biden" doesn't help.

No, it does not go outside the meaning. Words are used on contexts, not in any void. I defined the general meaning and then applied it to the context. That is something you did not do. Let's be clear about that. I even gave another example in a sentence.

Finally, the verb is to zigzag. Going in one direction and then changing direction is the base meaning. Not: To zig and to zag both mean to make a sharp turn, but when used together they usually mean turning in different directions, such that when alternating, the turns create a zig-zag.

@Lambie zig: to move in one of the two directions followed in a zigzag course

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The upshot of the remark about Montana zagging when others are zigging is that Montana is unpredictable.  The phrase has that ability there is synonymous with "can, as everyone knows".

Montana can, as everyone knows, follow a course that is contrary to expectation and prevailing trends.


This conversation was getting rather lengthy, so these comments have been moved to chat. Comments continuing this discussion may be removed.

There's a lot of disagreement here and you might be more confused about this than you were when you asked.  There are a number of answers here.  None of them are outright wrong and some primarily address the title of your question, and some try to address the specific quote and what is meant by it in context.  Unfortunately, I don't think any of them really get the context of the quote quite right.   In terms of general question around the idiom 'what does "zigs when others zag" mean?', see Maciej Stachowski's answer.
As far as the specific quote goes, there are a lot of details required to really understand it.  First off, this is not about the presidential election as stated/implied in some of the answers.  The entire article is about senate elections.  Specifically, the section this idiom appears in is about an upcoming election for one of Montana's 2 senate seats. The context of the quote relates to the incumbent senator from Montana since 2006: Jon Tester. So why is Biden mentioned? The reason that's relevant is that senate elections occur every 6 years while presidential elections are every 4 years. (Side note: not every senator is up for reelection at the same time.) It's a well-known phenomenon that when a senator or house seat election aligns with the presidential election, the turnout for elections tends to be much higher compared to 'off-years' when there are no presidential candidates on the ballot.
In 'off year' elections where there is no presidential election, a smaller subset of the voting populace shows up at the polls. They tend to be older and more politically aware. Tester barely won in his last (off-year) election.
In the last presidential election (2016) when Tester was not on the ballot, Trump won the Montana electoral college votes by an overwhelming 15 (percentage) points over Biden. In most states, you can expect that voters will vote along 'party lines'.  That is, most of the people who turn out to vote for Trump will vote for 'down ballot' Republicans as well. A lot of Trump supporters will only show up when Trump is on the ballot. All of these facts look bad for Tester.
So finally, we can now get to the meaning of the phrase "zags when other zig" in this context. It's important to understand that the person quoted is an unnamed source who is a political operative likely speaking 'off the record', not a politician who is running for office. The idea they are trying to convey is that perhaps the Montana voters will not vote along party lines as expected in other similar elections for incumbent Democrats in Trump-supporting states.  That is, they will go against the national trend and Trump voters will also vote for the incumbent Democrat Senator or abstain.
As to what is meant by 'Montana has that ability', I think we can presume that refers to Montana's tendency to not follow the rest of the country in some (I think) surprising ways. For example, Montana is the only state in the US which doesn't follow a primarily 'at-will' employment regime.

the verb is to zigzag: It means to move in one direction and then turn sharply and move in the other direction.
He ran up the hill in a zigzag pattern.
So, people take zig and zag and apply it to situations.
For example: We don't agree on how to solve a problem. There are two solutions. I could say: You zig on this while I zag. [when we know those two solutions]
In the extract from The Hill, the full quote is needed:

The former president won the state by more than 15 points four years
ago, with that margin potentially increasing as President Biden’s
standing in the polls has dipped nationwide.
“It’s going to be tough,” one Democratic operative conceded. “But
Montana has that ability to zag when people zig.”

So, the operative is saying that even if Biden is not doing well in nationwide polls, in Montana he will do well because Montana goes in a different direction than other states.

I would find "You zig on this while I zag" a very strange form of the idiom in that case. I found one war movie using "you zig, I'll zag" to mean physically separating so that somebody survives, but I don't see it used about a disagreement. (I'd usually say "why don't you try your way and I'll try mine", "let's agree to disagree" or if I was really reaching for an idiom, "You take the high road, I'll take the low road", "let's divide and conquer", "to each their own", etc)

(I agree w/ you & Maciej about the meaning of the Montana excerpt though.)

@Kaia It does not matter how zig and zag are used in an utterance. There are two main points: they come from the verb to zigzag and they have to appear at some point in one or two sentences, never just one or the other and there are tons of ways this can happen. Finally, I said zero about agreement/disagreement.

Whether people up-vote this or not, this is absolutely the right answer. To "zig when you should zag" builds on "zigzag". It means you went one direction when you should have went the other, or implies someone or something will do the opposite people expect.

For example, I can't tell you how many times I've taken a turn while driving and uttered, "Oops! I zigged when I should have zagged." upon realizing I turned left when I should have turned right.

And this is a very context-dependent idiom. It does not necessarily imply a direction of travel. I can be a direction of opinion (for versus against something). Or the direction of stock prices, for instance. If you expect stock prices to go up, but instead they go down, you could say "stock prices zigged instead of zagged." Or describe opposing decisions. For instance, if I sold stock just before prices rose, I might say "I zigged when I should have zagged" to imply I sold the stocks too soon before prices rose.

@GregBurghardt Yes, the point is direction and a change thereof.

I suppose, in incredibly rare cases, "you zig I'll zag" has been used literally. (As in the war movie example.) Probably no more often than "You take the high road, I'll take the low road" has been used literally.

@Fattie It could be two cops chasing a criminal in a city, too. For example.

@Lambie Re: "never just one or the other" As an example of using one without the other, I occasionally use the slang "zag on em", meaning "do something expected or out of character to keep them guessing". e.g. "I've been pretending to not know anything about movies at work, so I can really zag on em at the trivia party when I reveal my vast trivia knowledge." The "zig" there is implicit/implied. (This is a niche usage, it doesn't change your main point). Wiktionary also has a "zag" quote without zig.

I think my objection to the "there are two solutions" "you zig on this while I zag" example, after some more thought, is that it lacks the sense of "sudden, sharp, chaotic turns". I think the war movie quote works well because the characters are about to be running for their lives in a battlefield. Likewise, a police chase, a stock market jump, or the Biden surge the Montana dems are hoping for are all sudden, unexpected turns. (As a extreme example, when going our separate ways after a first date, I wouldn't say "Well, it's been great, but it's time for you to zig and me to zag"!)

Overall I think this answer is correct but "in Montana he will do well because Montana goes in a different direction than other states" isn't really what is meant.  The point is to suggest that it's not a lost cause and with enough effort they could win a senate seat there. It sounds more like wishful thinking than a confident expectation.

@Kaia, there is no chaos in the idea of zigzag. The main idea is a clear or sharp change of direction. The two solutions, fyi, is that you can vote Democrat or Republican. [sigh]
